# Is there any way to port WPF application to Windows IoT?

Tags: wpf, windows, uwp, iot

We have developed a WPF application runs great on Windows 10. At this point we are looking for ways to run this software on a Minnowboard. This board has a Windows IoT OS. As I've seen it is only capable to run UWP applications. Is there any way to make our app run under IoT? Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, no, WPF is about as portable as a white elephant.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly the problem I am facing with... Seems like we will need to use Windows 10.

Answer (score 6):

Of course you can port your code. Depending on how complex your app is, it still might need some rewriting as many APIs are not available anymore, have changed or were added.

Maybe these links help you:

- [Move from WPF and Microsoft Silverlight to WinRT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn263237.aspx) on MSDN
- [UWP Bridge tool](http://www.mobilize.net/uwp-bridge) by Mobilize.NET
- [UWP samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples) by Microsoft on Github

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! It is a very complex application actually. It controls industrial printers.

Comment: Whereas the UI then might be no crucial, better look at the UWP API and whether it actually has the API to control the printers. I also added a link to some categorized UWP samples by MS on GitHub.

Answer (score 2):

[Windows 10 IoT Enterprise version](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/WindowsForBusiness/windows-iot) enables WPF apps